# Issue with loading SVG image in VSCode extension's web view - ERR_ACCESS_DENIED

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

Description:
I'm developing a VSCode extension with a web view component that includes an SVG image. However, when I try to load the SVG image in the web view, I encounter the following error in the browser's console:

`GET vscode-webview://<unique_id>/media/bin-icon.svg net::ERR_ACCESS_DENIED`

I have already tried the following:

- Updated the Content Security Policy (CSP) in the HTML file to allow
  img-src vscode-webview: data:;.
- Ensured that the SVG image file exists in the specified location and
  is accessible.
- Verified the file path and confirmed it matches the
  actual location of the image file.
- Tested with different SVG images    and other types of image files
  (e.g., PNG, JPEG).

Despite these attempts, the error persists. I'm wondering if there are any additional steps or considerations to resolve this issue and successfully load the SVG image in the web view of my VSCode extension.

Comment: Exact same issue with angular framework. I think we have to add it in the panel conf.

Comment: so were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the 'localResourceRoots' in 'createWebviewPanel' ?

```js
window.createWebviewPanel(
    'viewtype', 
    'title', 
    {
        // And restrict the webview to only loading content from our extension's `media` directory.
        localResourceRoots: [
            Uri.joinPath(_extensionUri, 'media')
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).